# iOS Pin It SDK with no documentation and sample code

Tags: ios, objective-c, pinterest

I'm trying to go through the basic tutorial on [Pinterest's website.](http://developers.pinterest.com/ios/)

the link for downloading documentation and iOS sdk doesn't provide documentation or sample code.there was only bundles in it

here is my viewcontroller.m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <Pinterest/Pinterest.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIButton* pinItButton = [Pinterest pinItButton];
    [pinItButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(pinIt:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:pinItButton];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)pinIt:(id)sender
{
    Pinterest *pinterest = [[Pinterest alloc]initWithClientId:@"1431885" urlSchemeSuffix:@"pin1431885"];
    [pinterest createPinWithImageURL:@"http://www.warrenphotographic.co.uk/photography/bigs/10122-Silver-and-red-kittens-white-background.jpg" sourceURL:@"http://placekitten.com" description:@"Pinning from Pin It Demo"];
}

@end
```

my code is fairly straight forward, i just couldn't get it running on my dev iphone
it kept throwing:

```
2013-06-06 17:17:27.787 Pinterest Testing[9403:907] -[__NSCFConstantString absoluteString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c86c
2013-06-06 17:17:31.626 Pinterest Testing[9403:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString absoluteString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c86c'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x32f4d3e7 0x3ac48963 0x32f50f31 0x32f4f64d 0x32ea7208 0x1a9f9 0x1a71d 0x34e47087 0x34e4703b 0x34e47015 0x34e468cb 0x34e46db9 0x34d6f5f9 0x34d5c8e1 0x34d5c1ef 0x36a745f7 0x36a74227 0x32f223e7 0x32f2238b 0x32f2120f 0x32e9423d 0x32e940c9 0x36a7333b 0x34db02b9 0x19f4d 0x3b075b20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are sending your URLs as `NSString` objects. `NSString` doesn't have a `-absoluteString` method, this is what the crash log is telling you.

The declaration of the Pinterest method (in Pinterest.h) is as follows:

```
- (void)createPinWithImageURL:(NSURL *)imageURL
                    sourceURL:(NSURL *)sourceURL
                  description:(NSString *)descriptionText;
```

You need to send `NSURL` objects, not `NSString`'s for the `imageURL` and `sourceURL`.

So for your case:

```
- (void)pinIt:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *imageURL     = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.warrenphotographic.co.uk/photography/bigs/10122-Silver-and-red-kittens-white-background.jpg"];
    NSURL *sourceURL    = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://placekitten.com"];

    Pinterest *pinterest = [[Pinterest alloc]initWithClientId:@"1431885" urlSchemeSuffix:@"pin1431885"];
    [pinterest createPinWithImageURL:imageURL
                           sourceURL:sourceURL
                         description:@"Pinning from Pin It Demo"];
}
```

Comment: thanks, is there anyway to check if Pinterest app is installed or not? if not, i can still launch the old web view.

Comment: you can use this function  BOOL canPinWithSDK = [objPinterest canPinWithSDK];

Comment: hey how to come back to app after posting image , callback is not working

Answer (score 0):

A quick glance at the header reveals that you should be passing in `NSURL` instances as the values for the imageURL and sourceURL, so once you do that it will no longer complain about trying to invoke `absoluteString` on an `NSString`.

The readme docs are probably not up to date with the API. This happens. A lot.

You probably need to do:

```
[pinterest createPinWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.warrenphotographic.co.uk/photography/bigs/10122-Silver-and-red-kittens-white-background.jpg"] sourceURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://placekitten.com"] description:@"Pinning from Pin It Demo"];
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers for the exceptions have already been given. I found the location of the sample project. You can download it from https://pinterest-ota-builds.s3.amazonaws.com/PinItDemo.zip

When you look at the sample file you can see that the `urlSchemeSuffix` is appended to your URL scheme. The following code is taken from the sample project:

```
[[Pinterest alloc] initWithClientId:@"1234" urlSchemeSuffix:@"prod"]
```

This means you have to register the following URL scheme in your app: `pin1234prod`.

This make make sure the callback works. You can also create the Pinterest client without suffix and the callback will also work with URL scheme `pin1234`