# pinterest api not giving response ( http://pinterestapi.co.uk/username/pins )

Tags: ios, pinterest

I have used this url **http://pinterestapi.co.uk/username/pins** for getting the pins from my account . Previously it is working but now it is not giving proper response . The output is `{"body":[],"meta":{"count":0}}` . At the starting it have some data for the key "Body" . So Based on that I have parsed the `json` . Please tell me how to solve this problem . Platform is `**iOS**` .

Comment: hi @ernaidu see my question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290315/share-video-on-pinterest it may help you..

Comment: Thanks for the url but my intension is to get the pins from my account  but not sharing .

Comment: yes, but I tried it but it never returns any type of information like Facebook...

Comment: Actually few days back it is working but now it is not working dont know what the issue is

Comment: i also used this but not succeeded https://www.mashape.com/ismaelc/pinterest-1#!documentation

Comment: http://pinterestapi.co.uk "Update 02/07/13

**Pinterest have changed how their site works so the scraper no longer works correctly.** There is no planned fix at the moment, apologies."